# Jenkins Kubernetes, podTemplates and inheritFrom

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

Good evening all, quick question about inheritFrom in podTemplates

I have defined a number of pod templates, each to serve their own discrete function, eg, npm, maven, gradle, etc.  My thought is in each project's Jenkinsfile, one can (at least from what I understand) then list all the podTemplates to cover the project build in question via the inheritFrom property.  Therefore, it becomes trivial for developers to easily bring in various pods without fussing with yaml directly.

For example, from the Jenkinsfile, I have:

```
    agent {                                                           
      kubernetes {                                                  
          defaultContainer 'jnlp'                                   
          nodeSelector 'cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: jenkins'     
          inheritFrom ['NPM SONARQUBE']                             
      }                                                             
    }
```

Again, from what I understand from the Kubernetes plugin, I *should* be able to define a list of pod templates to inherit from.  However, in this case, this is throwing an exception because the npm container doesn't exist in this case.  If I only attempt one item in inheritFrom, eg,

```
inheritFrom "NPM"
```

It works just fine.  What am I missing here?  FWIW, all my pod templates merge strategy is set to 'merge' and not override.

Also, each pod template looks like the following, where the only difference is the name and image used, obviously:

```
kind: Pod                                                           
metadata:                                                           
labels:                                                             
  component: ci                                                     
spec:                                                               
  # Use service account that can deploy to all namespaces           
  serviceAccountName: fnord                                    
  containers:                                                       
    - name: sonarqube                                                 
      image: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest                     
      command:                                                        
      - cat                                                           
      tty: true
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it?

Answer (score 1):

You can define like,

```
agent {                                                           
      kubernetes {                                                  
          defaultContainer 'jnlp'                                   
          nodeSelector 'cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: jenkins'     
          inheritFrom 'NPM SONARQUBE ANOTHER-TEMPLATE'                            
      }                                                             
    }
```

This works well with Jenkins 2.254 and Kubernetes 1.19 and Kubernetes plugin version in Jenkins 1.25.7.